# Flutter combine futuerbuilder and streambuilder

Tags: flutter

i need some guidance how to combine a futurebuilder with a streambuilder. For example, the futurebuilder will load the comments which are stored in my Mysql database, while the streambuilder will fetch new comments and add them to the listview. The stream and future works perfectly, but i have no idea how i will combine these two things with eachother.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _fetchComments(39),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: commentProvider.channel.stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot2) {
          return ListView.builder(
            key: PageStorageKey("CommentsScroll"),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final comment = snapshot.data[index];
              return CommentTile(
                key: Key(DateTime.now().toString()),
                photoUrl: comment["photo_url"],
                displayName: comment["display_name"],
                created: comment["created"],
                text: comment["text"],
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: use `StreamBuilder` only and pass a `Stream` which combines stored and new comments - in other words: combine your data, not widgets

Comment: Will the problem not if i pass the comments into the websocket stream, it will load for everyone multiple comments